# Best fit line is not according to the results while using np.linspace() with matlotlib

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, matplotlib, keras, deep-learning

**For those who are not familiar with the ML part, please just take a look a look at the last code section. First codes are to ask if there is some problem with plotting or the ML model**

I am trying to learn custom training using `tf.GradientTape()` and made a custom model as:

```
class RegressionModel(tf.keras.Model): # every new model has to use Model
    '''
    A Model that performs Linear Regression 
    '''
    def __init__(self,in_units,out_units):
        '''
        args:
            in_units: number of input neurons
            out_units: number of output units
        '''
        super(RegressionModel,self).__init__() # constructor of Parent class 
        
        self.in_units = in_units
        self.out_units = out_units
        
        self.w = tf.Variable(tf.initializers.GlorotNormal()((self.in_units,self.out_units))) 
        # make weight which has initial weights according to glorot_normal distribution
        
        self.b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(self.out_units)) # bias is mostly zeros
        
        self.params = [self.w,self.b] # we can use the model.params directly inside the GradientTape()
            
    
    def call(self,input_tensor):
        '''
        execurte forward pass
        args:
            input_tensor: input tensor which will be fed to the network
        '''
        return tf.matmul(input_tensor, self.w) + self.b
```

I made my loss and gradients functions as:

```
def compute_loss(model,x_features,y_true):
    '''
    Calculate the loss. You can use RMSE or MAE 
    args:
        model:  a model that'll give  predicted values
        x_features: Array of data points
        y_true: respective target values
    '''
    y_pred = model(x_features)
    error = y_true  - y_pred
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(error)) # MSE: Mean Squred Error



def compute_grad(model,x_features,y_true):
    '''
    Compute the Gradient here
    '''
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        loss = compute_loss(model,x_features,y_true)
        
    return tape.gradient(loss,model.params) # you see model.params. It'll include all the params
```

and I trained the model as:

```
losses = []
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01)
model = RegressionModel(1,1) # 1 feature columns and 1 output for regression easy for plotting
print(f"Initial:\n{model.w}\n{model.b}\n\n") # model's initial weights and biases

for epoch in range(500):
    gradients = compute_grad(model,X,y)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients,model.params)) # apply back prop to all the "trainable" params
    
    losses.append(compute_loss(model,X,y)) # make a list of loss per epoch

print(f"Final:\n{model.w}\n{model.b}")
```

**PLOTTING PROBLEM**:

Problem is that I made a method for generating the data points according to `y=mx+c` and then tried predicting it on the model. If you generate the data as:

```
def generate_random_data(shape=(100,1)):
    '''
    Generate correlated X and y points which are correlated according to straight line  y=mx+c
    args:
        feat_shape: {tuple} shape of the X data
    '''
    X = np.random.random(shape)* np.random.randn() - np.random.randn() # complete randomness
    m = np.random.random((shape[1],1))
    c = np.random.randn()
    y = X.dot(m) +  c + np.random.randn(shape[0],1)*0.13 # add some noise too
    return X,y

X,y = generate_random_data()  # try generating the data different times to see performance of model


X = X.astype(np.float32) # default is double or float 64 in numpy
y = y.astype(np.float32) # tf would have converted it to float32 automatically


reg_x_points = np.linspace(X.min(),X.max(),100)
reg_y_points = model.predict(reg_x_points.reshape(-1,1)).flatten()

plt.plot(reg_y_points,reg_y_points)
plt.scatter(X,y)
plt.show()
```

It is not showing the line at all? I trained the data on same X and y but the best fit line is far from the data points and showing unusual behaviour. Is it because of the network, training, data or the plotting part?

Comment: In the first `plt.plot` you are using `reg_y_points` twice, meaning the line won't be drawn over your data. Should it be `plt.plot(reg_x_points, reg_y_points)`?

Comment: Sorry. My bad. That was the problem. Thank you.